# mysql column name and field value as row

Tags: mysql, row, pie-chart

I am trying to feed a data visualization program which uses sql queries. In order to create a pie chart, it wants the input to look as follows:

```
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|SliceName|SliceValue
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|Slice 1  |1
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|Slice 2  |5
+--+-----+-----+-----+
```

Our product data is stored in a table like this:

```
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|ProductID|Slice 1 | Slice 2
+--+-----+-----+-----+
|123      |1       |5
+--+-----+-----+-----+
```

Additional products being stored on additional rows. We need to retrieve one of these rows using the ProductID, then create sql output which looks like the table in the first example. I have read some posts about "pivoting", but I'm not sure that is exactly what we need to do here.

Can anyone offer some pointers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/1729885

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Is this what I need? This approach doesn't output the names of the columns from the initial table as rows. That is the thing I'm struggling the most with. I don't need to do any new counting, or summing. All the values are already present. I just need to basically turn a row into a table.

Comment: Yep, that's what pivoting is about, and what is explained in the answers to that other question. SQL is about rows, the field names are just decoration. Pivoting is not a native capability of SQL therefore - metadata like the field name cannot suddenly become a 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change your database schema (and do you have the appetite to do so)? Your problem could be resolved by looking at data normalisation and the relationships within the database.

I would take the information relating to the slices out of the **Products** table and into a new table called **Slices**.

Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d56a9/4) example.

You'll see that I've created a FK in the **Slices** table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProductID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So that if you delete a row from the **Products** table, the data in the **Slices** table that relates to that `ProductID` will also be deleted. Also if you were to update the `ProductID` in the **Products** table, then this change would be cascaded to the **Slices** table too.

Now to get the data in the format that you want, you could either `SELECT` from **Slices** direct using `ProductID` or use a SQL statement with an `INNER JOIN` to `SELECT` based on another column in the **Products** table, e.g.

```
SELECT SliceName, SliceValue
FROM Slices s
INNER JOIN Products p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE ProductName = "widget"
```

Storing your slices in a separate table like this be more efficient and provide flexibility; unless you always have a fixed number of slices for every product.